# My "+" operator is ambiguous in my fixed update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm trying to introduce movement into my game and I am running into this error that "operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type 'vector3' and 'vector2'"
PLEASE HELP

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody rb;

    Vector2 movement;

    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a 3D or 2D game? You seem to be mixing 3D types (`RigidBody.Positon`) with a 2D movement vector.

Comment: `Vector2 movement;` change to `Vector3 movement;` If you are 2d Game , you can use RigidBody2D Compoent , and also use vector2 well

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use the + operator on a Vector3 and a Vector2 object. Unity doesn't know how to handle that so you need to cast one of them, whichever one makes sense in the context, to match the other.

So probably:

```
rb.MovePosition((Vector)rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Comment: the cast should be written as `(Vector2)rb.position + ...` However, in this case I would probably rather cast the `movement` to `Vector3` since `MovePosition` expects a `Vector3` so it will anyway be casted back to a `Vector3`

Answer (score 0):

you can't use "+" operand between **rb.position** and **movement** .

you can use every vector Separately like :

```
X= (movement.x)+(rb.position.x) ;
Y= (movement.y)+(rb.position.y) ;
```

and then use X and Y in your code

```
Vector2 v = new Vector2 (X,Y);
```